# Items added to a Panel are overlapping.

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, panel, overlap

When I'm adding items (`RadioButtons`) to a panel, they are displayed on top of each others :

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
   this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(new RadioButton() { Content = ... );
}
```

[image]

Why is that and how can I make them appear on top of each other ?

Comment: Use a listbox with databinding

Comment: What type is ContentPanel?

Comment: If you are using code (outside XAML) to generate controls in WPF for something simple, you're doing it **wrong**. Create a ItemsControl, bind it to a list of pubs. Create a DataTemplate which defines that Pub is displayed with a RadioButton and bind the properties of the control to the button

Comment: Think about using DataBindings and ItemTemplating

Comment: It sounds like `ContentPanel` is a panel type that allows controls to overlap, such as a `Grid` or `Canvas`. Change it to a panel that arranges its items in a specific layout, such as a `<StackPanel>` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably want to move that to your xaml in general.

But to fix your current issue add the radio buttons to a horizontally aligned stack panel or grid then add that stack panel / grid to your content panel